# Issue converting path to raw string while loading it to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a list which has the path of the all the csv files that I need. I need to take the content of each csv file and append to a dataframe. But while using the pd.read_csv funtion since the path needs to a be a raw string I am getting an error. Since this has to be done in a loop i want to know how it can be done. Could anyone help?

My list is similar to how its shown below.

```
path_list = [C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy1.csv,
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy2.csv...]
append_list = []

for csv_path in path_list():
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    append_list.append(df)

append_list = pd.concat(append_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around each of the strings to make a list, so change:

```
path_list = [C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy1.csv,
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy2.csv...]
```

To:

```
path_list = [r’C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy1.csv’,
r’C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Csv_files\copy2.csv’]
```

The reason for using r’ is that your strings include \ - this is one way of handling that.

There are other ways.

Python works very happily on Windows using / instead of \ as path separator, so you could also use:

```
path_list = [’C:/Users/varun/Desktop/Csv_files/copy1.csv’,
’C:/Users/varun/Desktop/Csv_files/copy2.csv’]
```

Another way would be to escape the \ by doubling them:

```
path_list = [’C:\\Users\\varun\\Desktop\\Csv_files\\copy1.csv’,
   ’C:\\Users\\varun\\Desktop\\Csv_files\\copy2.csv’]
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. It is working.

Comment: You’re new to StackOverflow otherwise I wouldn’t say this: if my answer answered your question you could accept the answer and optionally upvote the answer.

Comment: Hi @ barny, I accepted the answer. I tried upvoting but it was not accepted since my reputation is low.